# Custom "signal received" activity not working

Tags: c#, signals, elsa-workflows

I want to implement a custom activity which behaves like `Signal Received` – means it “suspends” the workflow and when I called it from a client-side (Postman) to resume and continue.
I don’t want to use the existing `Signal Received` since I want to have some additional logic before suspending the workflow in the same action.
I followed the guidelines from [here](https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/next/guides/guides-blocking-activities).

So I implemented `Signal Custom` activity based on [SignalReceived](https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/blob/master/src%2Fcore%2FElsa.Core%2FActivities%2FSignaling%2FActivities%2FSignalReceived%2FSignalReceived.cs) default activity.

```
using System;
using Elsa.Activities.Signaling.Models;
using Elsa.ActivityResults;
using Elsa.Attributes;
using Elsa.Expressions;
using Elsa.Services;
using Elsa.Services.Models;

namespace Elsa.Workflows.CustomActivities.Signals
{
    [Trigger(
        Category = "Custom",
        DisplayName = "Signal Custom",
        Description = "Custom - Suspend workflow execution until the specified signal is received.",
        Outcomes = new[] { OutcomeNames.Done }
    )]
    public class SignalCustom : Activity
    {
        [ActivityInput(Hint = "The name of the signal to wait for.", SupportedSyntaxes = new[] { SyntaxNames.JavaScript, SyntaxNames.Liquid })]
        public string Signal { get; set; } = default!;

        [ActivityOutput(Hint = "The input that was received with the signal.")]
        public object SignalInput { get; set; }

        [ActivityOutput] public object Output { get; set; }

        protected override bool OnCanExecute(ActivityExecutionContext context)
        {
            if (context.Input is Signal triggeredSignal)
                return string.Equals(triggeredSignal.SignalName, Signal, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            return false;
        }

        protected override IActivityExecutionResult OnExecute(ActivityExecutionContext context) => context.WorkflowExecutionContext.IsFirstPass ? OnResume(context) : Suspend();

        protected override IActivityExecutionResult OnResume(ActivityExecutionContext context)
        {
            var triggeredSignal = context.GetInput<Signal>()!;
            SignalInput = triggeredSignal.Input;
            Output = triggeredSignal.Input;
            context.LogOutputProperty(this, nameof(Output), Output);
            return Done();
        }
    }
}
```

I created the`SignalCustomBookmark.cs`:

```
using Elsa.Services;

namespace Elsa.Workflows.CustomActivities.Signals.Bookmark
{
    public class SignalCustomBookmark : IBookmark
    {
        public string Signal { get; set; } = default!;
    }
}
```

and `SignalCustomBookmarkProvider.cs` as well:

```
using Elsa.Services;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Elsa.Workflows.CustomActivities.Signals.Bookmark
{
    public class SignalCustomBookmarkProvider : BookmarkProvider<SignalCustomBookmark, SignalCustom>
    {
        public override async ValueTask<IEnumerable<BookmarkResult>> GetBookmarksAsync(BookmarkProviderContext<SignalCustom> context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) => await GetBookmarksInternalAsync(context, cancellationToken).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

        private async IAsyncEnumerable<BookmarkResult> GetBookmarksInternalAsync(BookmarkProviderContext<SignalCustom> context, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var signalName = (await context.ReadActivityPropertyAsync(x => x.Signal, cancellationToken))?.ToLowerInvariant().Trim();

            // Can't do anything with an empty signal name.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(signalName))
                yield break;

            yield return Result(new SignalCustomBookmark
            {
                Signal = signalName
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I also registered the new bookmark in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`:

```
services.AddBookmarkProvider<SignalCustomBookmarkProvider>();
```

I created a test workflow and add this custom `Signal Custom` with `test-signal` as signal.

I can start the workflow using the api and it's working fine - once the instance gets to that `Signal Custom` the workflow becames suspended.
I start the workflow using this call from Postman:

```
https://localhost:5001/v1/workflows/{workflow_id}/execute
```

But then I want to resume it by triggering this call

```
https://localhost:5001/v1/signals/test-signal/execute
```

with this body

```
{
    "WorkflowInstanceId": "{Workflow_Instance_Id}"
}
```

Postman returns 200Ok with this body

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "startedWorkflows": []
}
```

Could you please guide me how to resume the workflow from client-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `https://localhost:5001/v1/signals/test-signal/execute` endpoint won't work for you because internally, it uses `ISignaler`:

```cs
await _signaler.TriggerSignalAsync(signalName, request.Input, request.WorkflowInstanceId, request.CorrelationId)
```

The default implementation of `ISignaler`, in turn, does this:

```cs
var normalizedSignal = signal.ToLowerInvariant();

return await _workflowLaunchpad.CollectAndExecuteWorkflowsAsync(new WorkflowsQuery(
    nameof(SignalReceived),
    new SignalReceivedBookmark { Signal = normalizedSignal },
    correlationId,
    workflowInstanceId,
    default,
    TenantId
), new WorkflowInput(new Signal(normalizedSignal, input)), cancellationToken);
```

Notice that the above code snippet is building a workflow query using the **SignalReceived** activity and the **SignalReceivedBookmark** bookmark.

These are not the same query parameters that you need in order to trigger workflows starting with or blocked on your custom **SignalCustom** activity and **SignalCustomBookmark** bookmark type.

In other words, you need to take two more steps to make it work:

1. Implement a custom controller (assuming you want to trigger your custom signal from a controller;)
2. Invoke IWorkflowLaunchpad.CollectAndExecuteWorkflowsAsync yourself instead of relying on `ISignaler`.

Better yet: define a new service called `ICustomSignaler` and have its implementation do the work.

For example:

```cs
public interface ICustomSignaler
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Runs all workflows that start with or are blocked on the <see cref="SignalCustom"/> activity.
   /// </summary>
   Task<IEnumerable<CollectedWorkflow>> TriggerSignalAsync(string signal, object? input = null, string? workflowInstanceId = null, string? correlationId = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

public class CustomSignaler : ICustomSignaler
{
   public async Task<IEnumerable<CollectedWorkflow>> TriggerSignalAsync(string signal, object? input = default, string? workflowInstanceId = default, string? correlationId = default, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var normalizedSignal = signal.ToLowerInvariant();

    return await _workflowLaunchpad.CollectAndExecuteWorkflowsAsync(new WorkflowsQuery(
        nameof(SignalCustom ),
        new SignalCustomBookmark{ Signal = normalizedSignal },
        correlationId,
        workflowInstanceId,
        default,
        TenantId
    ), new WorkflowInput(new Signal(normalizedSignal, input)), cancellationToken);

}
```

Your custom controller could then look something like this:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("custom-signals/{signalName}/execute")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class Execute : Controller
{
    private readonly ICustomSignaler _signaler;
    private readonly IEndpointContentSerializerSettingsProvider _serializerSettingsProvider;

    public Execute(ICustomSignaler signaler, IEndpointContentSerializerSettingsProvider serializerSettingsProvider)
    {
        _signaler = signaler;
        _serializerSettingsProvider = serializerSettingsProvider;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Handle(string signalName, ExecuteSignalRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var result = await _signaler.TriggerSignalAsync(signalName, request.Input, request.WorkflowInstanceId, request.CorrelationId, cancellationToken).ToList();

        if (Response.HasStarted)
            return new EmptyResult();

        return Json(
            new ExecuteSignalResponse(result.Select(x => new CollectedWorkflow(x.WorkflowInstanceId, x.ActivityId)).ToList()),
            _serializerSettingsProvider.GetSettings());
    }
}
```

We're tracking two issues to see if we can provide a way to allow users to extend the **SignalReceived** activity without having too much custom code:

- https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/issues/1035
- https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/issues/1053

Comment: Thank you for your fast and detailed response!
Your suggested solution works like a charm :).
BTW this workflow tool is really awesome.
You did a very good job. Congrats!

Comment: This was helpful, i had capital letters in the signal name in the workflow. Making the signal lowercase based  on the above fixed the problem